# Dart method not called

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I have the following code in dart/flutter project with BLoC

```dart
abstract class BasePage extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget get body;

  const BasePage({@required Key key}) : super(key: key);

  Bloc create(BuildContext context) {
    final dao = Provider.of<LessonsDao>(context, listen: false);
    return LessonListBloc(dao)..add(LoadListEvent());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final blocs = createBlocs(context);
    return BlocProvider(
      lazy: false,
      create: (context) {
        return create(context);
      },
      child: Material(child: body),
    );
  }

}
```

Now, when i want to change the create's function return type to `Bloc`, the subscriber widget, that is listens to the LessonsListLoaded that is `yield` in by the LessonListBloc, is not delivered to the `body` Widget:

```dart
Bloc create(BuildContext context) {
    final dao = Provider.of<LessonsDao>(context, listen: false);
    return LessonListBloc(dao)..add(LoadListEvent());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You depend on LessonListBloc

But BlocBuilder can't get it

The case is you narrowing the type in create function  LessonListBloc -> Bloc

this will work

```
create(...)
LessonListBloc create(...)
```

this will not

```
Bloc create(...)
```

Rewrite you code with types and analisator will pop types mismatch error

```
BlocProvider<LessonListBloc>(...
```